# Displaying JSON url in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, json

Is there a way to publish a JSON URL that displays a live feed of current bus vehicle locations in ArcGIS Online?

Here's the URL: https://transitdata.phoenix.gov/api/vehiclepositions?format=json

Comment: To clarify, that URL is an example of what you would like to generate? Or are you looking to consume a JSON-formatted API and display it live on a map?

Comment: I would like to attempt to consume a JSON-formatted API and display it live on a map, preferably AGOL.

Comment: As far as I know, ArcGIS Online cannot add a layer from the web that is in the json or geojson format. It can add both from a file, but it can't consume them from a URL. I would love for someone to correct me.

Comment: Due to the limitations with AGOL, would working with ArcGIS API for JavaScript be the alternative route?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so... https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/using-fromjson/index.html This page might be a start.

Answer (score 4):

Koop may help you with this - https://koopjs.github.io/ - http://koop.dc.esri.com/

It is an:

> An Open Geospatial ETL Engine

that lets you:

> Leave geospatial data where it lives and transform it into GeoJSON,
>   CSV, KML, a Shapefile, or a Feature Service dynamically.

The feature service can then be consumed by ArcGIS online